# Load different template file for different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page for which I want to load **different template file** for **different browsers.**

**Example :**

If browser is **IE** then load **1.tpl**

& If browser is other than IE load **2.tpl**

[ Here `.tpl` is template file having **respective** content & css ]

I tried using conditional tags :

```
<!--[if IE]>
{include file="/templates/1.tpl"}       
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>-->
{include file="/templates/2.tpl"}   
<!--<![endif]-->
```

With these conditional tags Other browsers are working perfectly fine. But IE still fetching content from both `.tpl` files resulting messy page.

So I did **trick** like this...

```
<!--[if IE]>
{include file="/templates/1.tpl"}  
<![endif]-->

<div id="container">
{include file="/templates/2.tpl"}  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
if(IE){
   $("#container").css("display","none");
}
 </script>
```

At **Front-end**, This is displaying what I needed,

But at the **Back-End** IE still have to **process** content & css of `both.tpl` And then **hide** one of them.

This resulting in heavy **loading time** & Javascript **conflict**.

I know these are *dirty trick* I have played.

Is there any **better way** to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

{include file="/templates/2.tpl"} is smarty tag which used in template customization files.

Comment: The better way is to take a light touch and provide the bare minimum of IE specific stuff rather than trying to maintain two different templates.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're doing. What processes the `{include file="/templates/1.tpl"}` code and includes the files? Why are you testing this client-side? Also I second what David said. It's best if possible to have a base style and provide a few IE specific styles (if absolutely necessary) on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "not IE" conditional comment is incorrect ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx)). Try:

```
<!--[if IE]>
{include file="/templates/1.tpl"}       
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
{include file="/templates/2.tpl"}   
<![endif]>
```

Note that the "not" version *isn't* using the `!--` form.

But as David said, the better way to do this is to use a single template that conforms to standards with a bare minimum nod to IE's....eccentricities, and if necessary include an extra template that augments that with some extra code for IE. This not least because since the smarty tags get replaced server-side, you'll always end up sending *both* templates to all browsers, just with one of them commented-out, which seems wasteful...

Comment: Is the 'not IE' conditional comment valid HTML though?

Comment: @BoltClock: I defer that question to Microsoft. :-) It *looks* like an SGML processing instruction, but... (And the W3C validator says no, but it's not always good at edge cases.)

Comment: @ BoltClock : Look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it using javascript.

```
function dynamicStyle(){

var ie_href = "ie-style.css"
var other_href = "other-style.css";

var style = document.createElement('link');
style.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');

    if(navigator.appCodeName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
        style.setAttribute('href', ie_href);    
    }

    else{
        style.setAttribute('href', other_href); 
    }

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);  
}

window.onload = dynamicStyle;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But it is .tpl file not .css
Also I need to perform Include function for .tpl which Javascript doesn't support- I guess